# Cassandra 2.0.6 won't startup on CentOS 6.5 EC2 micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, centos

I have a fresh install and followed the install steps from Datastax. For some reason, when I try to start, this is all I get... non-informative "killed" message.

```
bash-4.1$ cassandra -f
 INFO 02:24:13,374 Logging initialized
 INFO 02:24:13,464 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 02:24:14,409 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 02:24:14,411 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO 02:24:14,411 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO 02:24:14,411 disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 02:24:14,412 commit_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 02:24:14,427 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 72MB
 INFO 02:24:14,727 Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO 02:24:15,260 JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_60
 INFO 02:24:15,261 Heap size: 301727744/302776320
 INFO 02:24:15,262 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 647168(632K)     committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
 INFO 02:24:15,262 Eden Space Heap memory: init = 61341696(59904K) used = 48067200(46940K) committed = 61341696(59904K) max = 61341696(59904K)
 INFO 02:24:15,262 Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 7602176(7424K) used = 0(0K) committed = 7602176(7424K) max = 7602176(7424K)
 INFO 02:24:15,263 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 232783872(227328K) used = 0(0K) committed = 232783872(227328K) max = 233832448(228352K)
 INFO 02:24:15,263 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 14299016(13963K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 85983232(83968K)
 INFO 02:24:15,271 Classpath: /etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stress.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-internal-only-0.3.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
Killed
```

I tried setting the IP address in the /etc/hosts file as well as reviewing the /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml file. Everything seems normal.

Comment: I would suspect its being killed due to lack of memory. Micro instances have only 613MB of physical memory, of which a portion is used by the system. Your app will probably only be able to use around 256MB.